# Best Practice for separating Web App Publish to IIS using VS Build Definitions

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I have done a fair amount of research for publishing and deploying web apps with VSTS and so far I have found the following:

1.Use .pubxml files and pass the DeployOnBuild = True to MSBuildArguments

2.Copy and publish Artifacts and create a separate release definition.

We are currently using the first method, but found that the build can be marked as successful but the publish fails (in our case it was a bad transform) 
So we decided to look into separating the publish step and to create a release for our changes. 
[image: soft fialure]

The issue I am running into is that the copy files and publish artifacts step only copies DLLs and our .js and .html/.css changes don't seem to make it to the UI. As a work around I added these params to the Copy Files method but it is taking a long time to publish. (There are no issues with the release definition)

```
 **\*
!$tf\**
**\!$tf\**
**\!Debug\**
**\*!pdb
```

All the guides online for using the Publish Artifacts and creating a separate release definition seem to say the same thing, and only push Dlls from the bin folder to the IIS server.

Here is my build definition:
[image: Build Definition]

So my question is, why aren't UI changes being deployed to the website when the release completes if this isnt an issue anywhere else?

Comment: Which task are you using to publish the artifacts?

Comment: @virusstorm I updated my post to show how my build is setup

Comment: I don't have an prem server to test this with, so I'm going off of memory. I think your `Copy Files` is correct and you have everything in the right sequence. You can verify this by taking look at the artifacts with the build. If you see your content files, then your issue is with the release. If you don't see the files, it's definitely the `Copy Files` task.

Comment: Yea that's what is weird but the publish fails due to the large amount of files, the agent times out.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. We usually not only publish DLLs and our .js and .html/.css as build artifacts, but for the whole web app.

The **Visual Studio Build task** usually with the MSBuild Arguments as (if you use ASP.NET build template, it's the default setting):

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

In this way, the web app (published files) will be copyed to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` directly. So you don’t need the Copy Files task.

If you need to deploy all files, you can use `**` in **Copy Files task**.

Then when you deploy the app to IIS server in release definition, the whole web app in build artifacts will be downloaded.

Comment: Ok, It looks like this was in my build definition in MSBuildArguments before so not sure why the web app isn't deploying properly. I will check again to see if the quotes and backslash will make a difference for Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory

Comment: So I updated the build arguments to this and it looks like it deployed a bunch of files to my wwwroot folder with a deploy.cmd file, and my solution.zip which I assume came from BuildArtifactStagingDirectory. So it didnt actually deploy anything to show my changes?

Comment: The MSBuild arguments just placed the files from the Publish Artifacts step in my wwwroot folder and I didnt see my changes reflected in the other folders.

Comment: If you need files more than wwwroot folder to be added to build artifacts, please use **Copy Files task**, and use `**` as the contents, then all the files will be added.